# Delete all files on ftp created before 10 days from now

Tags: bash, ftp

Is there a command to delete all files with a certain name created a couple of days ago from my ftp server, running ubuntu 14.04?

Here is what I have

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Which is the location for the files you want to delete? A folder on your local machine? A remote folder in the FTP server? Where do you want to delete them from?

Comment: _"Is there a command"_ - no, but you can combine multiple commands. What have you tried?

Comment: I want to delete them from the ftp server. As those are backup files for a live system I'm a bit too concious to try a combination by myself, can you assist @CodeCaster

Comment: You don't test scripts on live environments. Setting up an FTP server on your local machine or a staging server is a couple clicks worth of work. Experiment there, and when you feel confident, move to production.

Comment: True thing @CodeCaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on the ftp server (with mydir changed into your dir).

```
find mydir -type f ! -mtime 5 -exec echo rm {} \;
```

When the echo shows what you like, remove the echo.